# Can I stay in Spain after my residence permit expires, but while waiting to get married?

Tags: resident-permit, marriage, spain, eu-spouses, legal

I have a residence permit as a student in Greece, which expires on the **31st of July.** I'm currently in Spain, waiting for appointment to get married to a Spanish citizen. We started the marriage procedure more than 3 months ago, beginning in March. We got the okay from the Court of Justice, but its schedule is full and we're still waiting for their call for us to sign the final papers.

Will I have problems if I stay in Spain until we get married and leave just after that?

Answer (score 1):

Once your visa expires, you could be considered “situación irregular” and, in Spain, some things are not so easy if you are ‘irregular.’

All non-EU-EEA and Swiss citizens who want to stay Spain for longer than three months have to apply for Tarjeta de Residencia (TIE), the residence card, doneat the Foreigner's Office (Oficina de Extranjeros) or police station in the province where you're living.

If you haven’t done that and, now, no longer have a valid visa, the District Court (Juzgado) may finalize the marriage but, when you leave,  you could be hit with a requirement on how long you have to remain outside Spain, such as 12 months, not exactly ideal for newlyweds.

You may wish to consult an attorney, after having a look at this Spanish Law Tribune article on [Getting Married In Spain: General Overview and Legal Issues For Foreigners In Irregular Situation](http://belegal.com/wordpress/getting-married-in-spain-general-overview-and-legal-issues-for-foreigners-in-irregular-situation/)